# Give an alert when a button is clicked in javascript with no Id

Tags: javascript

Ok so this is being a pain the the butt. I have tried every which way to get this to happen but it is not working. I want an alert for when this button is click.

The html is

```
    <div class="btn btn-default" style="width: 44px;" ng-class="{'active btn-success': hasCategory(category)}" ng-click="processAnswer(category, true)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
  </div>
```

and after the button is clicked it changes to

```
    <div class="btn btn-default active btn-success" style="width: 44px;" ng-class="{'active btn-success': hasCategory(category)}" ng-click="processAnswer(category, true)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
  </div>
```

I have been using

```
    $("").click(function() {
alert("button was clicked");
});
```

and

```
    document.getElementByClass('btn btn-default active btn-success').onclick = function() {
alert("button was clicked");
};
```

What my final aim to do is call a function when this button is clicked but that is easy enough to do if I just replace the alert which I have been using to test.

Comment: Why don't you just give it an id?

Comment: Is that possible? I'll look into it to see how to give it an id.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). This will return an array of the DOM nodes that meet your class name criteria.

Then you can simply specify which element you want by index.

For example, if it's the only button on the page, you can access it at index [0].

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default active btn-success')[0].onclick = function() {
  alert("button was clicked");
};
```

If you're trying to accomplish this using jQuery, you can use the `.classname` convention to select classes like this:

```
$('.btn .btn-default .active .btn-success')[0].onclick(function() {
  alert("button was clicked");
});
```

**Lastly, it may be easier to simply give it a unique ID and access it that way, using [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):**

Change the HTML like this:

```
<div id="buttonId" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 44px;" ng-class="{'active btn-success': hasCategory(category)}" ng-click="processAnswer(category, true)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
  </div>
```

Then add the listener like this:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function() {
  alert("button was clicked");
};
```

You should also consider moving the click event to the `<i></i>` icon, instead of its container `<div>`.

Comment: Not getting a alert still. Used both the before and after class names.

Comment: I've tried with the icon earlier with no luck and just tried again with nothing.  If I could automatically add an id to the html then it would be simple. Moving the click event to the i icon would look like this right.         `document.getElementsByClassName('glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up').onclick(function() {
  alert("button was clicked");
});`